# I get an error that there is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter "Project" of " Program.DisplayProjectSummary(Project) "

Tags: c#

I get an error that there is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter "Project" of "Program.DisplayProjectSummary(Project)".

```
class Program
{
    static Portfolio portfolio = new Portfolio();

    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add a new project");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Show existing projects");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Select a project");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Remove a project");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Display summary total for the selected project");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Display summary total for the entire portfolio");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Exit");

            Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");
            int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    AddNewProject();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ShowExistingProjects();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SelectProject();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    RemoveProject();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    DisplayProjectSummary();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    DisplayPortfolioSummary();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Try again.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void AddNewProject()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the project ID: ");
        int projectId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Is it a new build project? (Y/N): ");
        bool isNewBuild = Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        Project project = new Project(projectId);
        portfolio.AddProject(project);

        Console.WriteLine("Project added successfully!");
    }

    static void ShowExistingProjects()
    {
        var projects = portfolio.GetProjects();
        if (projects.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No projects found.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Existing Projects:");
        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Project ID: {project.ProjectId}, New Build: {!project.GetPurchases().Exists(t => (t as PurchaseTransaction)?.IsNewBuild == true)}");
        }
    }

    static void SelectProject()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the project ID: ");
        int projectId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var project = portfolio.GetProjects().Find(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);
        if (project == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Project not found.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Project ID: {project.ProjectId}, New Build: {!project.GetPurchases().Exists(t => (t as PurchaseTransaction)?.IsNewBuild == true)}");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add a new transaction");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Display all sale transactions");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Display all purchase transactions");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Display a summary total for the project");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Back to main menu");

            Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");
            int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    AddTransactionToProject(project);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DisplaySalesForProject(project);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    DisplayPurchasesForProject(project);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    DisplayProjectSummary(project);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Try again.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void AddTransactionToProject(Project project)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter transaction type (S for sale, P for purchase, L for land purchase, R for renovation): ");
        string transactionType = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter transaction amount: ");
        decimal amount = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Transaction transaction;
        switch (transactionType.ToUpper())
        {
            case "S":
                transaction = new SaleTransaction(project.ProjectId, amount);
                break;
            case "P":
                Console.Write("Is it a new build purchase? (Y/N): ");
                bool isNewBuild = Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                transaction = new PurchaseTransaction(project.ProjectId, amount, isNewBuild);
                break;
            
            case "L":
                transaction = new PurchaseTransaction(project.ProjectId, amount, true); // Land purchase is considered a new build
                break;
            case "R":
                transaction = new PurchaseTransaction(project.ProjectId, amount, false); // Renovation purchase is not a new build
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid transaction type. Try again.");
                return;
        }

        project.AddTransaction(transaction);
        Console.WriteLine("Transaction added successfully!");
    }

    static void DisplaySalesForProject(Project project)
    {
        var sales = project.GetSales();
        if (sales.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No sale transactions found for this project.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Sales for Project ID {project.ProjectId}:");
        foreach (var sale in sales)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Amount: {sale.Amount}");
        }
    }

    static void DisplayPurchasesForProject(Project project)
    {
        var purchases = project.GetPurchases();
        if (purchases.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No purchase transactions found for this project.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Purchases for Project ID {project.ProjectId}:");
        foreach (var purchase in purchases)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Amount: {purchase.Amount}, Is New Build: {(purchase as PurchaseTransaction).IsNewBuild}");
        }
    }

    static void DisplayProjectSummary(Project project)
    {
        decimal totalSales = project.GetTotalSales();
        decimal totalPurchases = project.GetTotalPurchases();
        decimal totalProfits = project.GetTotalProfits();
        decimal taxRefund = project.GetTaxRefund();

        Console.WriteLine($"Project ID: {project.ProjectId}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Sales: {totalSales}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Purchases: {totalPurchases}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Profits: {totalProfits}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Tax Refund Expected: {taxRefund}");
    }

    static void DisplayPortfolioSummary()
    {
        decimal totalSales = portfolio.GetTotalSales();
        decimal totalPurchases = portfolio.GetTotalPurchases();
        decimal totalProfits = portfolio.GetTotalProfits();
        decimal totalTaxRefund = portfolio.GetTotalTaxRefund();

        Console.WriteLine("Portfolio Summary:");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Sales: {totalSales}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Purchases: {totalPurchases}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Profits: {totalProfits}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Tax Refund Expected: {totalTaxRefund}");
    }

    static void RemoveProject()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the project ID to remove: ");
        int projectId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var project = portfolio.GetProjects().Find(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);
        if (project == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Project not found.");
            return;
        }

        portfolio.RemoveProject(project);
        Console.WriteLine("Project removed successfully!");
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error? I have tried everything. This is a program meant for building a project that shows a menu and displays the project summary and other options as well depending on what option the user chooses.

Comment: Your case 5 in `Main` doesn't compile: `DisplayProjectSummary();`. There is no overload of `DisplayProjectSummary` without `Project` parameter. By the way, i don't think it would compile otherwise because i don't see the property/field `portfolio` either, which you are using often.

Comment: thank you, this was just a small snippet of the code.

Comment: So you have understood the reason of the compiler error? You call `DisplayProjectSummary` without giving a mandatory `Project` as parameter. So what you actually want to do here? Mabe you want to provide a new overload of `DisplayProjectSummary` which shows all projects summaries or better provide a new method `DisplayAllProjectSummaries` for it.